# I want to save the selected rows in tableview and during searching it will maintain it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Here is my code, someone help me?
In this example i display list of items and during searching the search items are displayed in the table view by using filterarray.
but i need to maintain the selection during searching after reload the table view.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
  //  self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    _button=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    _tableListArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Suresh kumar",@"Nanda kumar",@"Cheese",@"Jam",@"Pizza",@"Burger",@"Roll Pizza",@"Butter Bread",@"Bread",nil];
    _filteredListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_tableListArray];
    NSLog(@"fiter=>%@",_filteredListArray)  ;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // return [_tableListArray count];
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //return [_tableListArray count];
    return [_filteredListArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView
```

dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

```
    if (cell==nil) {

        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[_filteredListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"filterarray=>%@",_filteredListArray);
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // i want to know what can i do here
}

#pragma mark-TextFieldDelegate
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    _textFld.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"textfield%@",_textFld);
    NSString *myString=_textFld.text;
    if (myString.length==0) {
        _filteredListArray=_tableListArray;
    }
    else
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[cd] %@",myString];
        _filteredListArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_tableListArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    }

    [_tableView reloadData];
    return  NO;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep an `NSMutableArray` of `NSIndexSet`. On each `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` check if the `indexSet` is in the array.
1. If so, remove it
2. If not, add it

This array will not change when you reload your tableView.